Estimating Gas Cost for Smart Contract Deployment Using Foundry
I'm trying to estimate the gas cost for deploying a smart contract using Foundry. Can someone provide guidance on how to do this accurately?

To estimate the gas cost for deploying a smart contract using Foundry, you can follow these steps:

Enable Gas Reports in Foundry Configuration: First, you need to enable gas reports in your Foundry configuration. This can be done by adding the contract names for which you want to generate gas reports to the foundry.toml configuration file. For example:
gas_reports = ["MyContract1", "MyContract2"]

This configuration tells Foundry to generate gas reports for the specified contracts.

Generate Gas Reports: After enabling gas reports in your configuration, you can generate these reports by running the forge test command with the --gas-report option. This command will execute your tests and generate gas reports for the contracts specified in your configuration. The command looks like this:
forge test --gas-report



